# Sending messages to non-Stomp/Websocket consumers

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp

I've added the Stomp/Websocket support to my application which has made sending notifications from the server side to the web clients for easy.  However, since this requires a server side message broker, I'm wondering if its possible to make server side components subscribe to "topics" published from the server?

For example, I'm using SimpMessagingTemplate to broadcast certain status updates to all connected Stomp clients, but can I also have an object on the server side subscribed as well?

My solution right now is a bit of a hack.  Instead of using SimpMessagingTemplate, the server side produces notification type broadcasts using Project Reactor where one of my consumers is a bridge that relays the message using SimpMessagingTemplate.  This allows my Java components as well my Stomp clients to get the update, but it seems like overkill to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could also register a ChannelInterceptor on the "brokerChannel". That is the channel to which the SimplMessagingTemplate sends messages. That will allow you to detect all messages flowing from the application to the message broker.

This may be enough for many cases, however in a more distributed environment there may be multiple application instances in which case you'll only detect messages from one application instance. We could consider providing some mechanism for receiving broker messages given a list of topics. You would simply configure the list of topics and provide a MessageHandler. If you could please [create a ticket in JIRA](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR).